# Boostrap sticky footer in laravel

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've got a laravel project with bootstrap added as css.
I've tried anything to get my sticky footer to work but as soon the page is longer then the window it stays at the bottom of the window when scrolled up.

My main:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Justin van Horssen</title>
    {{-- Bootrstrap 4.1.1 CSS --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        @include('inc.nav')
    </header>
    <main role = "main" class="container">
        @include('inc.messages')
        @yield('content')
    </main>
    @include('inc.scripts')
    <footer class="footer">

    </footer>
</body>
```

My footer CSS:

```
.footer

    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 60px;
        background-color: #003b6f;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some problem with your html or body CSS.

As per the [bootstrap 4 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer), the CSS should be like:

```
 html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
 }

 body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
 }

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #003b6f;
}
```

For more ways to get a sticky footer, check out [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer).

Thanks..hope it helps..cheers.

Comment: Could you link the bootstrap doc that you are talking about?